# Spring can't find external properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm kicking off a sub process

```
pb = new ProcessBuilder().inheritIO().command(java, "-noverify", "-cp", classpath, 
                String.format("-Dspring.config.name=file:///%s", myConfigFile.getAbsoluteFile()),
                clazz.getCanonicalName());
```

And when I run Spring debug, I get

```
could not find key 'spring.config.name:application' in any property source
```

And naturally I cannot access my properties.

I should note that my company is currently only allowing Spring-Boot 1.5 :-(

1 - I'd like to use an external configuration. This program is basically a "launcher" for another program, in which they're choosing their configuration
2 - I've also tried spring.config.location.

Am I missing something in terms of what I need to do to read an external properties file? Is there anything else I can look at?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to recognize my file after renaming it "application-whatever.properties".